# Update a complex SQL query to add a new column with the sum of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below SQL query creates a table with `n number of columns` named in the next line.

`....`, `curr_amount`, `tax_amount`, `....`

I am having a very tough time updating the below query to create a new column called `total` and `position` it exactly after `tax_amount` column and the `total` column should contain the values that are obtained after sum of `curr_amount` & `tax_amount`.

I have been working on this from more than one day but couldn't figure it out.

P.S. Still a noob here. Thanks alot for your time. 
.

```
SELECT Isnull(t.total_month, 'Total') total_month, 
       t.tax_amount, 
       t.curr_amount, 
       t.usage_qty, 
       t.kh_qty, 
       t.bill_cnt 
FROM   (SELECT dbo.Sigmadf(bm.posted_date, 'YYYY-MM') total_month, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN rr.usage_qty IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE Cast (rr.usage_qty AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) 
                   END)                               usage_qty, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.curr_amount IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE bm.curr_amount 
                   END)                               curr_amount, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.adj_amount IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE bm.adj_amount 
                   END)                               adj_amount, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.bal_fwd_amount IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE bm.bal_fwd_amount 
                   END)                               bal_forward, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.tax_amount IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE bm.tax_amount 
                   END)                               tax_amount, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.due_amount IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE bm.due_amount 
                   END)                               due_amount, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.last_total_paid_amount IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE bm.last_total_paid_amount * -1 
                   END)                               paid_amount, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bm.bill_print = 'Y' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)                               pdf_cnt, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN Isnull(bm.bill_handling_code, '0') = '0' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)                               reg_cnt, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN Isnull(bm.bill_handling_code, '0') = '1' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)                               ftime_cnt, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN Isnull(bm.bill_handling_code, '0') = '9999' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)                               ltime_cnt, 
               Count(*)                               bill_cnt, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bill_status = '01' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)                               canc_cnt, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN bill_status = '01' THEN 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN rr.usage_qty IS NULL THEN 0 
                         ELSE Cast (rr.usage_qty AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) 
                       END 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)                               canc_usg, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN vis.kh_qty IS NULL THEN 0 
                     ELSE Cast(vis.kh_qty AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) 
                   END)                               kh_qty 
        FROM   bill_master bm WITH (nolock) 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT bill_no, 
                                  Sum(CASE 
                                        WHEN vpb.recurr_charge_type IN ( 'T4', 
                                             'SLF' ) 
                                      THEN 
                                          CASE 
                                            WHEN vpb.print_qty = 'Y' 
                                                 AND vpb.usage_qty IS NOT NULL 
                                          THEN 
                                            Cast (vpb.usage_qty AS 
                                                  NUMERIC(18, 2)) 
                                            ELSE 0 
                                          END 
                                        ELSE 0 
                                      END) usage_qty 
                           FROM   v_print_bills_all vpb 
                           GROUP  BY bill_no) rr 
                       ON rr.bill_no = bm.bill_no 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN vis_bill_master_cr vis WITH (nolock) 
                            ON bm.bill_no = vis.bill_no 
        WHERE  1 = 1 
               AND dbo.Trunc(bm.posted_date) >= '20150101' 
               AND dbo.Trunc(bm.posted_date) <= '20151124' 
               AND bm.posted_date IS NOT NULL 
               AND bm.cust_id NOT IN (SELECT cc.code_type cust_id 
                                      FROM   code_table cc WITH (nolock) 
                                      WHERE  cc.code_tabname = 'RptExclCust' 
                                             AND cc.code_value = 'cust_id') 
        GROUP  BY dbo.Sigmadf(bm.posted_date, 'YYYY-MM') WITH rollup)t
```

Comment: Can you perhaps make a smaller example? It's very hard to understand a problem when you have to scroll around, both for you and for us.

Comment: but it the query that I am working with and having difficulty my friend

Comment: Side note - but very important. This appears to be a financial application. Please do yourself a favor and stop using NOLOCK. Dirty reads should be enough reason to avoid this for this type of application but it brings so many other data inconsistencies to the table. It will sometimes return missing and/or duplicate rows which is really bad for your aggregates. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Also if performance is an issue here you have several scalar functions which are very bad from a performance perspective.

Comment: When asking a programming question, you really should try to be precise.  Your question mentions a `tax` column and an `amount` column, yet there are no columns with those exact names in your code.   Use exact names so people don't have to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I must say that the explanation is not so clear.
From my understanding, you want the total of two columns.

So, wrap all your query between parenthesis, call it *subQuery*, and make the sum of the two columns on top:

```
SELECT subQuery.total_month as  bill_date, 
subQuery.curr_amount as amount, 
subQuery.tax_amount tax, 
subQuery.curr_amount + subQuery.tax_amount  as [total],
...
FROM
(..your entire query here..) as subQuery
```

Comment: SQL Server requires an alias for inline views.